# Gensim Word2Vec dimension change between 0.12.3 and 0.13.2

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I was wondering what changed in Gensim Word2Vec model between 0.12.3 and 0.13.2.

When I train a small sample of sentences on 0.12.3 (setting the size=2 for visualization). The distribution looks as follows:
[image]

When I do the same on 0.13.2 it looks like this:
[image]

Did the dimensions change to polar or something?